# What is the correct aproach to notify running application to update data when a push message arrives?

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I have a simple chat application which able to receive push notifications. I have registered a BroadcastRecevier in my manifest file for that. When a push message arrives this BroadcastRecevier saves the incoming data to database so when application started I can fetch unread messages. In oreder to notify the application to fetch data again while running in foreground I have an other BroadcastRecevier that defined in my activity and registered dynamically when application started. So my first BroadcastRecevier gets the data saves it to database and send a broadcast message for runtime BroadcastRecevier.

Use case 1: Application is not running

- BroadcastRecevier gets push message
- BroadcastRecevier saves message to db
- BroadcastRecevier sends a broadcast message for runtime BroadcastRecevier
- When application starts, read messages from db

Use case 2: Application is running

- BroadcastRecevier gets push message
- BroadcastRecevier saves message to db
- BroadcastRecevier sends a broadcast message for runtime BroadcastRecevier
- Runtime BroadcastReceiver gets the message and handles it

Is this a good practise?
Do you have an other better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a `service` or `listeners` to update the data from `broadcast receivers`.

Comment: you can use Otto or EventBus instead of your runtime BroadcastRecevier.

Comment: If you're using SQL, you can register a listener on the `Cursor` using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#registerContentObserver(android.database.ContentObserver) so the moment the `BroadcastReceiver` pushes to DB, the `Activity` gets notified by the DB itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends broadcast receivers are meant to handle short tasks so if you are performing a short function let the broadcast receiver handle (user case 2) if it is big or time taking use (user case 1)